# Uncaught TypeError while scraping data from bank

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, typeerror

I aim to scrape my personal account information automatically using JavaScript. Below is the code I inserted into my browser console after logging in.

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

function click_1 () {
   document.querySelector("#accountMaskLink-640332982").shadowRoot.querySelector("a > span.link__text").click();
}

function click_2 () {
 document.querySelector("#downloadActivityIcon").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").click();
}

click_1();
wait(8000);
click_2();
```

Please notice that the `wait` function is to wait for the site to render the next available menu. However, this doesn't work. Despite 8 seconds are long enough for the next menu to show, it still gives the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
    at <anonymous>:3:52
(anonymous) @ VM3475:3
```

**Question 1**: This doesn't happen if I enter the code line by line. What's going on?

*EDIT*

**Answer 1**: This is provided by @Bravo in the comment. When I use the sync version of `wait`, the menu renderer stops working too. So I have to use the async version.

Comment: synchronous "wait" means nothing else is happening on the site - maybe not even renders! - [this](https://pastebin.com/WuXku0rP) may work better - but that error suggests a different problem

Comment: What I really meant was to simulate a click after the menu is rendered. How should I change? Using an async wait seems to run the code that follows immediately..

Comment: async wait can work, if you know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bravo's hint, and some research, I've come up with a satisfactory answer.

1. Synchronous `wait` halts everything, including the menu renderer.
2. We need an async version.

```
function clickAccountInfo (ms) {
   document.querySelector("#accountMaskLink-640332982").shadowRoot.querySelector("a > span.link__text").click();
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function clickDownload (ms) {
   document.querySelector("#downloadActivityIcon").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").click();
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function selectMenuDownload () {
   document.querySelector("#downloadActivityOptionId").shadowRoot.querySelector("#select-downloadActivityOptionId").click();
   document.querySelector("#downloadActivityOptionId > mds-select-option:nth-child(2)").shadowRoot.querySelector("div").click();
   document.querySelector("#download").shadowRoot.querySelector("button").click()
}

await clickAccountInfo(15000);
await clickDownload(5000);
selectMenuDownload();
```